# No Persistence provider exception for web module

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have create one jpq project(jar) and have my Jpa code in that project for db operations.
Now I have a spring project(web module) where I have added that jpa prject as dependency. The problem is that when I try to run that web application I face one issue that "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Test_JPA_SEMICOLON" but When I run the test cases in that jpa project they execute properly. Following is the dependency I have added for the jpa project. Can you please guide me what should I try to fix that.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.vodafone.config-model</groupId>
            <artifactId>config-mode</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You know the file `persistence.xml` that JPA relies on? perhaps post it!

Comment: The issue is not with the persistence.xml. The problem is getting resolved if I add the hibernate dependencies in the web project as well. But my question is why I will add hibernate dependencies in the web project as I have already added these dependencies in the JPA project and that project is added in the web project dependency. I believe the issue can be fixed with some tricks in the pom.xml.

Comment: well yes, the problem is with persistence.xml since we dont see what is in it! If you have indeed defined hibernate as the provider then clearly you have to have Hibernate in your classpath / pom.xml but as said, we dont see it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to define the persistence provider name in the file `persistence.xml` after `<persistence-unit name="Test_JPA_SEMICOLON">`:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Comment: i have already mentioned that in the persistent.xml and its working properly when I run in that jar. the issue is when I run it in the web module. Somehow its not getting the hibernate dependency but the question is why?